# php error Message: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to EIC\EdiBundle\Service\SerialService::validateOrder() must be an instance

Tags: php

First let me start off by saying I am not a php programmer so php terminology I probably won't understand.

That being said I'm trying to solve this error with importing orders
can see that it errors on line 243 and 69 how ever as I said in no entirely sure what SerialService::validation must be an instance of salesOrderHeader means. I believe a null was given because the JSON file didn't get created as seen in the image of the database and I'm not sure why.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ley3k.png)

LineNo: 243
Message: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to EIC\EdiBundle\Service\SerialService::validateOrder() must be an instance of EIC\SalesBundle\Entity\SalesOrderHeader, null given, called in /var/www/eic/src/EIC/EdiBundle/Service/SerialService.php on line 69 and defined

**SerialService.php**

```
/**
     * @Route("/serial/{sender}", name="edi_serialize")
     */
    public function serializeAllNotImported($sender=null)
    {
        $orders = array();
        $documents = $this->em->getRepository('EICEdiBundle:Document')->findDocumentsNotSerialized($sender);
        $jpp = new JsonPrettyPrinter();
        /* @var $document Document */

        foreach($documents as $document){
            print_r("--- serializing doc id#: ".$document->getId()." ---\n");
//            print_r($document->getJsonOrder());

            try {
                $order = $this->serializeDocumentToEic($document);// ToDo if $order is not SalesOrderHeader Class email and continue
                $class = get_class($order);
                $orders[] = $order;
                $json = $this->serializer->serialize($order, 'json');
                $valid = $this->validateOrder($order); //line 70
                if ($valid === true) {
                    $document->setCustomerNumber($order->getCustomerNumber());
                    $document->setJsonOrder($json);
                    $this->em->persist($document);
                    $this->em->flush();
                } else {
                    $pjson = $jpp->format($json);
                    $errorMessage = $valid . "\n" . $pjson;
                    $this->emailError($errorMessage);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r('<<---------Exception-------->> <<-------SerialService------->>');
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r('File: '.$e->getFile());
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r('LineNo: '.$e->getLine());
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r('Message: '.$e->getMessage());
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r($e->getTraceAsString());
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                print_r('<<---------Exception End-------->>');
                print_r(PHP_EOL);
                continue;
            }

            print_r("--- end serializing doc id#: ".$document->getId()." ---\n");
        }
```

**Line 240 to 268**

```
protected function validateOrder(SalesOrderHeader $order){
        $error = false;
        $errorMessage = '';

        $customerNumber = $order->getCustomerNumber(); //line 244
        if(empty($customerNumber)){
            $error = true;
            $errorMessage .= 'Error: Can not import this order because the customer part number could not be determined'."\n";
        }

        /* @var $line SalesOrderItem */
        foreach($order->getLineItems() as $line){
            $stockNumber = $line->getStockOrdered();
            if(empty($stockNumber)){
                $error = true;
                $errorMessage .= 'Error: StockNumber -> Can not import this order because part number ( '.$line->getCustomerPartNumber().' ) could not be determined'."\n";
                $errorMessage .= "\t Please have the Catalog Dept. added to the interchange.\n";
                $errorMessage .= "\t This order will be processed, once the part number has been added to the interchange,  on the next run.\n";
            }
        }

        if($error===false){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return $errorMessage;
        }

    }
```

**ValidateService.php**

```
class ValidateService
{

    /* @var \AppKernel */
    protected $kernel;

    /* @var EntityManager */
    protected $entityManager;

    /* @var Serializer */
    protected $serializer;

    /* @var ImportService */
    protected $importService;

    /* @var \Twig_Environment */
    protected $twig;

    /* @var \Swift_Mailer */
    protected $mailer;

    public function __construct(\AppKernel $kernel, EntityManager $entityManager, Serializer $serializer, ImportService $importService, $twig, \Swift_Mailer $mailer){
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        $this->importService = $importService;
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function validateOrders(){
        $serializer = $this->serializer;
        $ediOrders = $this->entityManager->getRepository('EICEdiBundle:Document')->findJsonOrdersToBeValidated();

        $validatedArray =[];

        /* @var $ediOrder Document */
        foreach($ediOrders as $ediOrder){
            $jsonOrder = $ediOrder->getJsonOrder();
            /* @var $order SalesOrderHeader */
            $order = $serializer->deserialize($jsonOrder, 'EIC\SalesBundle\Entity\SalesOrderHeader', 'json');
            $co = $ediOrder->getCoNumber();
            $swOrder = $this->entityManager->getRepository('EICSalesBundle:Order')->findOneBy(['orderNumber'=>$co]);
            if(!empty($swOrder)){
                $validated = true;
                /* @var $lineItem SalesOrderItem */
                foreach($order->getLineItems() as $lineItem){
                    $lineNumber = $lineItem->getLineNumber();

                    $isLineNumberItems = $swOrder->getOrderItems()->filter(function($swLineItem) use ($lineNumber){
                        /* @var $swLineItem OrderItem */
                        return $swLineItem->getLineNumber() == $lineNumber ? true : false;
                    });

                    if($isLineNumberItems->count() < 1){
                        $validated = false;
                        $this->importService->importNewSingleOrderItem($order, $lineItem);
                        continue 2;
                    }else{
                        $validatedArray[] = $co;
                    }
                }

                if($validated == true){
                    $emailCusts = [
                        4267,
                        3017,
                        4436,
                        4068,
                        3054,
                        4214
                    ];

                    $validatedArray = array_unique($validatedArray);
                    $ediOrder->setIsSwOrderValidated(true);
                    $this->entityManager->flush();

                    $custNum = $ediOrder->getCustomerNumber();

                    if(in_array($custNum, $emailCusts)){
                        $orderArr = json_decode($jsonOrder, true);
                        $render = $this->twig->render('@EICEdi/Default/simple.order.html.twig', ['order'=>$orderArr, 'coNumber'=>$ediOrder->getCoNumber()]);

                        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('New Order Imported')
                            ->setFrom(['donotreply@eipump.com'=>'EI Central'])
                            ->setTo([
                                'twatkins@eipump.com'=> 'Trent Watkins',
                                'mdye@eipump.com'=> 'Marie Dye',
                                'cricci@eipump.com'=> 'Charlotte Ricci',
                                'fhammond@eipump.com'=> 'Fred Hammond',
                            ])
                            ->setBody($render, 'text/html');
                            ;

                        $result = $this->mailer->send($message);
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        return 'The following orders have been validated:'."\n".implode(',', $validatedArray);

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The code expects `$order` variable to be an object and instance of `EIC\SalesBundle\Entity\SalesOrderHeader` class.

Here you have `todo` comment that this function can return `null` insteand of object that is needed.
"ToDo" means that code must be done later
`$order = $this->serializeDocumentToEic($document);// ToDo if $order is not SalesOrderHeader Class email and continue`
You should not call `validateOrder`  function if `$order` is null
Add verification in your code before calling `$valid = $this->validateOrder($order); //line 70` function

```
if ($order === null || (is_object($order) && !instanceof EIC\SalesBundle\Entity\SalesOrderHeader) ( {
    // send email as TODO says and 
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and I will apply your suggestion. The reason its retuning null is because it not converting the document to json format. Is how it looks to me. So the real issue is why is it returning null and not a json document Is what I need to figure out.